# Spring 4 and JSF ViewScope

Tags: spring, jsf-2, view-scope, spring-4

In Spring 3 and JSF 2.0 when we wanted to use the JSF view scope we had to introduce custom ViewScope implementation and instruct Spring to pick it up through CustomScopeConfigurer.

Has Spring 4 made any progress in the JSF integration on this front? Or is it still needed to define custom ViewScope implementation to leverage view scope in spring managed beans?

Comment: my very personal impression is that nothing happened and will happen there. jsf moves towards cdi. and for spring i think, jsf does not play a big role anymore. they put more effort into thier newer projects with spring-data and REST-based web technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a confirmation from Spring staff of what @fischermatte mentioned: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6543

Comment: Thx for the link, it indeed seems like an official position not to invest too much effort into JSF support. Probably a good thing we decided to go with pure JavaEE for our new JSF based project.